# Excel 2013 change sheet with formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

With an older version of Excel (2007 and earlier) I could change the current workbook sheet with following formula:

```
=ACTIVATE("Sheet2")
```

But if I use the same formula in Excel 2013 it doesn't work properly. When I open the old Excel file containing this formula excel recognized it. If I create a new, empty excel document, the formula is unknown.

I also tried to find a documentation on MSDN about that formula but without any success.

Is there an other way to change the current workbook sheet by using a formula? I know it is possible with macro and it does work but in this particular case I need a formula.

**EDIT:**
In the meantime I figured out that there is a problem with Microsoft Excel 4.0 Macro Functions in Excel 2013. The formula I described above is a function from that macro library. As stated by Microsoft it is still supported in Excel 2013 but should not be used anymore. Does anyone know how to enable the compatibility?

I tried to enable all macros under the Thrust Center and I also enabled all the Macro 4.0 under File Blocktype.

Answer (score 1):

Use it as a *Method* rather than a *function:*

```
Sub dural()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub
```